# Devise: Wrong url generated in sign up confirmation email when last character is '-'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

@token is generated by devise:

```
@token = Devise.token_generator.generate(class, column)
```

then it goes to the

```
app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb

<% content_for :email_content,
auto_link(simple_format(t('mailers.confirmation_instructions',
              confirmation_url: confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @token))))
%>
```

If last character in @token string is '-' then it is not a part of generated confirmation URL, and raises "invalid token" error. Should I change generate method in Devise.rb? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was YAML. The confirmation URL is formed in `locales` -> `%{confirmation_url}` and when the last character was `-` it was not included in the URL.

**1.Method**

Inside the `.yml` file put confirmation_url into attributes `<a href=%{confirmation_url}> %{confirmation_url} <a>`

**Method 2**

There are two methods that generates it:  `generate_confirmation_token`, and `generate_confirmation_token!`. Both of them use `self.friendly_token` method:

```
def self.friendly_token(length = 30)
  # To calculate real characters, we must perform this operation.
  # See SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  rlength = (length * 3) / 4
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(rlength).tr('lIO0', 'sxyz')
end
```

Add `-`as exeption into the `.tr` method like this `.tr('lIO0-', 'sxyz')`.
After that, if `.friendly_token` method will generate one of these characters: `'lIO0'` .tr method will replece it with one of these `'sxyz'`. 
Override the method in your application with

```
Module Devise
  def self.friendly_token
    ...
  end      
end
```

Hope it will help someone in the future. It took a while to me.